# Wordpress Custom Post type - comments doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, comments, custom-post-type

I noticed that the comments on a Custom Post Type that the ID is higher than 9, doesn't work properly.

Is there any hack we can do?

Here's my code

in my functions.php file

```
// register post type MySpecialPost
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_MySpecialPost' );
function register_cpt_MySpecialPost() {
$labels = array( 
'name' => _x( 'MySpecialPost', 'MySpecialPost' ),
'singular_name' => _x( 'MySpecialPost', 'MySpecialPost' ),
'add_new' => _x( 'Ajouter', 'MySpecialPost' ),
'add_new_item' => _x( 'Ajouter une MySpecialPost', 'MySpecialPost' ),
'edit_item' => _x( 'Modifier', 'MySpecialPost' ),
'new_item' => _x( 'Nouvelle MySpecialPost', 'MySpecialPost' ),
'view_item' => _x( 'Voir la MySpecialPost', 'MySpecialPost' ),
'search_items' => _x( 'Recherche', 'MySpecialPost' ),
'not_found' => _x( 'Aucune MySpecialPost trouvé', 'MySpecialPost' ),
'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'Aucune MySpecialPost trouv&eacute;', 'MySpecialPost' ),
'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Service:', 'MySpecialPost' ),
'menu_name' => _x( 'MySpecialPost', 'MySpecialPost' ),
);

$args = array( 
'labels' => $labels,
'hierarchical' => false,


'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'author', 'page-attributes' ),            

'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_in_menu' => true,
'menu_position' => 21,

'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'has_archive' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'can_export' => true,
'rewrite' => true,
'capability_type' => 'page'
);
register_post_type( 'MySpecialPost', $args );
}
```

Comment: I'm on a fresh install of WP Version 3.4.2
This is the code I have for a custom post type:

And I'm using the default comment template provided by wordpress, without any custom callback:

<?php comments_template(); ?>

I have also checked 'allow comments' under 'Discussion' for this post type.

I DO NOTICED THAT THIS IS BECAUSE I HAVE WPML PLUGGIN INSTALLED.

I guess that there's something I can do! Let me know if you find the solution

Comment: I have found the solution!

A activated WPML support for your custom post type.

WPML > Translation Options
You should see a list of custom post types and you can set them to allow translation.